# Flash AS3 find closest point to handrawn path

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I have a path drawn in the flash IDE, accessible as a MovieClip.

With AS3 I need to find the closest point lying on this path to another point.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A trick I've used in the past is to convert the path to a motion guide, then create a simple timeline tween where a simple MC travels from start to finish. then export that animation as an Animation/XML. you've now got a list of points with timing info to use however you want.  (writing from my phone so I can't look up the exact syntax within the IDE.)